# Generic failure error in powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling, powershell-remoting

i Have a Powershell Script To Get the Another PS Script From Local Server and run PS Script
All systems in network give an "Generic failure" error when the server is not available Or That one error Exception Calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s) "The remote server returned an error : (404) Not Found."

```
start-sleep 120
$i=0    
While ($true) {
    if ($StatusCode = Test-Connection -ComputerName 192.168.1.1 -Quiet) {
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.168.1.2/service/ok.ps1'))
Break

     }
     }
```

Friends, what can I do when the server is not available or the system is not available with the internal network This message is not given this error and wait system to reach the local network or server ?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: You test connection to `192.168.1.1` and then try to run a script downloaded from `192.168.1.2`? That doesn't make much sense, unless the remote host has multiple IP bindings - and still strange an approach.

Comment: Why are you using `DownloadString` and not [DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile) if apparently what you want is to run that `ok.ps1` file?

Answer (score 0):

First ping the server to chck if it is online, if it replies then proceed. But you are pinging 192.168.1.1, but downloading file from 192.168.1.2 so you have to ping 192.168.1.2. Also set ErrorAction to SilentlyContinue in Test-Connection

```
start-sleep 120
$i=0    
While ($true) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName 192.168.1.2 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.168.1.2/service/ok.ps1'))
Break

     }
Else {
  "Generic Failure"
     }
```

**As you are getting a 404 error, then the requested file does not exist on the server. Check the URL. If the URL is valid, then the file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. The server seems to be in local network, so contact the server administrator.**